# Rails 3.1 - Conditional statements in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to use conditional statements in a Rails Model?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
if create
  before_save do
  self.position = self.track.position
  end
else
  acts_as_list :scope => :product_id
end
```

I basically want acts_as_list to be effective after the initial create has been done.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're looking for before_create.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_list :scope => :product_id
  before_create :set_initial_position

  private

  def set_initial_position
    self.position = self.track.position
  end
end
```